# Laravel Calendar.io using controller to display view

Tags: laravel, fullcalendar

this is my current codes i have written in my controller beside using the view itself as i would like to link it to my database.

I would like to ask whether i can actually create a custom attribute to change the display of the calendar... and it doesn't seem to work this way.

Or is it possible to set a fixed id on the calendar itself in the controller, and add a javascript/jquery to the view?

```
    $events = Appointment_List::all();
    $event_list = []; //  public static function event($title, $isAllDay, $start, $end, $id = null, $options = [])
    foreach ($events as $key => $value){
            $event_list[] = Calendar::event(
                $value->name,
                false,
                new \DateTime($value->start_date . 'T' . $value->start_time),
                new \DateTime($value->end_date . 'T' . $value->end_time)
            );
    }


    $custom_attr = ['defaultView'=>'listDay'];

    $calendar_details = Calendar::addEvents($event_list, $custom_attr);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 $calendar_details = Calendar::addEvents($event_list)->setOptions(['defaultView'=>'listDay']);
```

The following can be solved...